# How can I add a redirect to an article with Pelican?

Tags: pelican

I would like to have something in the header like

```
title: Whatever
slug: whatever
redirect: bla
redirect: foo
redirect: bar
```

so that Pelican generates pages which redirect from `bla` and `foo` and `bar` to `whatever`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just saw that this is called an "alias". There is the plugin [`pelican-alias`](https://github.com/Nitron/pelican-alias) which can be installed by `pip install pelican-alias`. Then `pelican_alias` has to be put into the `PLUGINS` list in `pelicanconf.py`. Aliases are then defined as

```
alias: bla, foo, bar
```